# Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found

Tags: python, keras

I'm using Amd's GPU so ı cannot install CUDA I know it's not error just notification something But how can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a warning. It’s trying to load cuda library.